# node graph extend to level 2nd and so on on downnode function in sijma js

Tags: sigma.js

Hi I am new to sigma js my issue is that I have created node graph and want to extend it to next level when any node get clicked. I do not find any examples in sigma js. can any one help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great place to start with is the sigma.js wiki on Github. In your case you should check out the Events API Page. https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki/Events-API

To bind a handler to a click event you have to use the bind function on the sigma object.

```
sigmaInstance.bind('clickNode doubleClickNode', yourEventHandler);
```

Comment: Hi Lukas thanks very much. Actually what I am doing right now is in a search box i search any node and its graph get created in sigma js. Now afterwards I want that from that particular graph when I click on any node it creates node graph or that clicked node. I am really confused as while searching its gives results on that (clicked) node but how to bind that on mousedown function I dont get any example as well. I am new to sigma js thats why getting issue. Thanks in advance